# How to scrape multiple pages from search results all at once

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape multiple pages from search results and print it all at once, but got an empty list instead.

Here is the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element_list = []

for skip in range(0, 20, 10):
    
    page_url = "https://jdih.esdm.go.id/index.php/web/result?tahun_terbit=2022,2021,2020,2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014&skip=" + str(skip)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(page_url)
    
    Tahun = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.numb separator')
    No_Peraturan = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.result-value')
    Nama_Peraturan = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.result__content__item__title')
    Deskripsi = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.result__content__item__desc')

    
    for i in range(len(Tahun)):
        element_list.append([Tahun[i].text, No_Peraturan[i].text, Nama_Peraturan[i].text, Deskripsi[i].text])

print(element_list)

driver.close()
```

The code return only return an empty list like in this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oul19.png)

*Note: the website does not use **'page'** as generally use for search results, but uses **'skip'** instead*

Anyone can help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector to find *Tahun* elements is incorrect as there are 2 classes assigned to the div. This results in *Tahun* being an empty list and since the loop to append text to *element_list* is based on the length of *Tahun*, nothing gets appended.

Update the selector to below.

```py
Tahun = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.numb.separator')
```